# Book class with default options (openright, twoside) produce wider right side margin for right side pages

Tags: margins, double-sided, books

Here is my LaTeX code for an example book:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Gravida neque
convallis a cras semper auctor. Quam id leo in vitae. Vel facilisis
volutpat est velit egestas. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum
sociis. Gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. A diam
sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi. Velit egestas dui id ornare
arcu. Ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Elit eget gravida cum sociis.
Diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui. Risus pretium quam
vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Ullamcorper dignissim cras
tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at.

Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Purus semper eget
duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis. Adipiscing tristique risus
nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit
amet risus nullam eget. Faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed.
Egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa. Urna id volutpat
lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu. Cursus metus aliquam eleifend
mi. Risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim. Nibh venenatis cras sed
felis eget. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec feugiat.
At volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu. Eget nulla
facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Turpis massa tincidunt
dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est. Sapien eget mi proin sed. Mauris
commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar. Ultricies mi eget
mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. Condimentum id
venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra.

Eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum.
Amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Tincidunt tortor
aliquam nulla facilisi. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus. Lorem
dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet. Feugiat in ante metus dictum at.
In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi. Diam in arcu cursus euismod.
Ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer. Elit eget gravida cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor.

Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu. Malesuada pellentesque elit
eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et. Neque laoreet suspendisse
interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Et leo duis ut diam. Purus sit
amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Massa tempor nec
feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Non arcu risus quis varius quam
quisque id. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Tellus mauris a
diam maecenas sed enim. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum
suspendisse ultrices gravida. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi
porta.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Gravida neque
convallis a cras semper auctor. Quam id leo in vitae. Vel facilisis
volutpat est velit egestas. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum
sociis. Gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. A diam
sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi. Velit egestas dui id ornare
arcu. Ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Elit eget gravida cum sociis.
Diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui. Risus pretium quam
vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Ullamcorper dignissim cras
tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at.

Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Purus semper eget
duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis. Adipiscing tristique risus
nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit
amet risus nullam eget. Faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed.
Egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa. Urna id volutpat
lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu. Cursus metus aliquam eleifend
mi. Risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim. Nibh venenatis cras sed
felis eget. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec feugiat.
At volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu. Eget nulla
facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Turpis massa tincidunt
dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est. Sapien eget mi proin sed. Mauris
commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar. Ultricies mi eget
mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. Condimentum id
venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra.

Eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum.
Amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Tincidunt tortor
aliquam nulla facilisi. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus. Lorem
dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet. Feugiat in ante metus dictum at.
In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi. Diam in arcu cursus euismod.
Ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer. Elit eget gravida cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor.

Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu. Malesuada pellentesque elit
eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et. Neque laoreet suspendisse
interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Et leo duis ut diam. Purus sit
amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Massa tempor nec
feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Non arcu risus quis varius quam
quisque id. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Tellus mauris a
diam maecenas sed enim. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum
suspendisse ultrices gravida. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi
porta.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Gravida neque
convallis a cras semper auctor. Quam id leo in vitae. Vel facilisis
volutpat est velit egestas. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum
sociis. Gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. A diam
sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi. Velit egestas dui id ornare
arcu. Ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Elit eget gravida cum sociis.
Diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui. Risus pretium quam
vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Ullamcorper dignissim cras
tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at.

Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Purus semper eget
duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis. Adipiscing tristique risus
nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit
amet risus nullam eget. Faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed.
Egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa. Urna id volutpat
lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu. Cursus metus aliquam eleifend
mi. Risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim. Nibh venenatis cras sed
felis eget. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec feugiat.
At volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu. Eget nulla
facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Turpis massa tincidunt
dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est. Sapien eget mi proin sed. Mauris
commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar. Ultricies mi eget
mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. Condimentum id
venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra.

Eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum.
Amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Tincidunt tortor
aliquam nulla facilisi. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus. Lorem
dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet. Feugiat in ante metus dictum at.
In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi. Diam in arcu cursus euismod.
Ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer. Elit eget gravida cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor.

Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu. Malesuada pellentesque elit
eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et. Neque laoreet suspendisse
interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Et leo duis ut diam. Purus sit
amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Massa tempor nec
feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Non arcu risus quis varius quam
quisque id. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Tellus mauris a
diam maecenas sed enim. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum
suspendisse ultrices gravida. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi
porta.
\end{document}
```

Here is the output I get:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

(On the left side above I have placed an artificial blank page to simulate how the pages would be laid out in a real book)

<kbd>[image]</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

(Pages 2 and 3 have less inner margin even though some part of the inner margin would be lost due to binding against the spine of the book)

Pages 1 and 3 have extra whitespace on the right side and page 2 has extra whitespace on the left side. Isn't it the opposite of what is desired considering new chapters open on right hand side, thus page 1 would be on right hand side?

Assuming page 1 is meant to be on the right hand side, it should have extra whitespace on the left side because the spine of the book is on the left hand side.

Is LaTeX doing the wrong thing here or is my understanding of how `twoside` and `openright` options work incorrect?

Comment: no latex is doing the right thing. Don't forget that in the middle of the book you have two margins: the left margin from the right page plus the right margin from the left page. Put the two pages side-by-side to see this.

Comment: This is the tradition in typography.

Comment: Have a look at Chapter 3 *The page* in my *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`> texdoc memdesign`) where many page layouts are shown covering many centuries and countries. They all illustrate the typographic tradition. LaTeX follows the tradition.

Comment: In the PDF does not matter, but in real thick books the defaults inner margins can be nearly lost,  and due to the page curvature, it is even difficult read the words near to the inner margins. There are many books real books with this problem. The problem is that LaTeX cannot know in advance how large would be your book. So, LaTeX is doing things well, but  this should not stop you from doing it better, considering a reasonable  *gutter margin* for your particular use case.  The best way to judge  is with your eyes and a real thick book with the same system of binding that you will use.